# HTML / Javascript append multiple words from data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-dataset

I am trying to append a text from a button to a modal window.

It works so far, but if the data contains more than 2 word, it just prints the first one what am I doing wrong?

```
...
<button type="submit" class="observeSubmit deleteProject" data-title={{ $productValue->title }} name="removeProj">
...
```

Js function:

```
$('button[name="removeProj"]').on('click', function(e){
    var $form = $(this).closest('form'); // closest parent form
    e.preventDefault();

    $("#prodTitle").empty().append($(this).data('title') || '-');

    $('#confirm').modal({ backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false })
    $('#delete').click(function() {
        $form.trigger('submit'); // submit the form
    });
});
```

So if I click on the button a modal opens and shows the value inside `$productValue->title`.

If `$productValue->title` holds for example Jon Doe.

The window just shows Jon.

I am not sure if it is due to the data attribute, maybe it can just hold one value, or if it due to the javascript function.

Comment: You need to wrap custom attributes in quotes i.e. `"{{ $productValue->title }}" `

Comment: Wow that fixed it :) would you like to answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap custom attributes in quotes.

```
<button data-title="{{ $productValue->title }}"></button>
```

Comment: This fixed it I'll accept the answer as soon as it is possible

Answer (score 0):

```
<button type="submit" class="observeSubmit deleteProject" data-title="{{ $productValue->title }}" name="removeProj">
```

The way it is now, it assigns the value "Jon" to data-title, and sees Doe as a seperate attribute.

Answer (score 0):

working fine here 
https://jsfiddle.net/

```
<form action="">
<button type="submit" class="observeSubmit deleteProject" data-title="test sdfg" name="removeProj">btntest</button>
</form>
<div id="prodTitle"></div>
$('button[name="removeProj"]').on('click', function(e){
    var form = $(this).closest('form'); // closest parent form
    debugger
    e.preventDefault();

    $("#prodTitle").empty().append($(this).data('title') || '-');

    $('#confirm').modal({ backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false })
    $('#delete').click(function() {
        $form.trigger('submit'); // submit the form
    });
});
```